# Why does the damage value for my weapon change?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Why does the damage weapon value keep changing in Skyrim? First I look into my inventory at my elven sword and see 106, then when I closed the inventory menu and reopened it again my elven sword is at 91.

Answer (score 11):

The damage done by a weapon is based not only on the weapon but on your weapon skill (One-handed in this case) and other effects. The inventory screen shows the actual damage dealt, not the base damage.

You must have had a temporary buff or piece of armor increasing your damage the first time you saw it.

Comment: BTW you can check these buffs under "Active Effects" in the magicka menu.